# How to fetch all childs from parent entity from core data, and how can i use the parent data as UITableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am setting parent as sections and child as number of rows in the section, but while fetching child from each parent, the parent which has only one child is displaying more than one, my code is to fetch data from core data

```
var projectsArray: [Project] = []
var foldersArray: [Folders] = []

let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Project>(entityName: "Project")
let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "pname", ascending: true)
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

let fetchFolders = NSFetchRequest<Folders>(entityName: "Folders")
let sortDesc = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
fetchFolders.sortDescriptors = [sortDesc]
do {
    let newProjectArray = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
    projectsArray = newProjectArray
    for newObj in projectsArray{
        if let projectId = newObj.id{
            fetchFolders.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "pid = %@",projectId)
        }
        do {
            foldersArray = try managedContext.fetch(fetchFolders)
            print("The folders are",foldersArray as Any)
        }catch{}
    }
}catch let error as NSError {
    print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    projectsArray = []
}
```

And in my controller i am reading like,

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return (newProjectArray != nil) ? newProjectArray!.count : 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection
        section: Int) -> Int {
        if newProjectArray![section].isExpandable == true{
            return (folders != nil) ? (folders!.count) : 0
        }
        else{
            return 0
        }
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection
        section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 40
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath:
        IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:
            "FoldersCell") as! FoldersCell
        if  newProjectArray![indexPath.section].isExpandable == true{
            let folder  = folders![indexPath.row]
            cell.projectNameLabel.text = folder.name
        }
        return cell
    }
```

Suppose say project called `ABC` contains one `folder` and project `XYZ` contains `folder1,folder2,folder3`, while displaying the cell `ABC` it is displaying `folder,folder1,folder2,folder3`, and while displaying the cell `XYZ` it is displaying `folder,folder1,folder2,folder3`, so what may be the good solution for this.

Comment: Do you have a relationship set up between Project and Folders entities in your Core data model?

Comment: Yes Joakim, one to may relationship from Projects to Folders

Comment: Then you don't need to perform a fetch separately for Folders, you can instead access them directly as a propert in code like `let projectFolders = project.folders`. Replace `folders` with whatever you named that relationship in the model

Comment: I was tried using that as well, faced same problem the code is `for newObj in projectsArray{

                    let new = newObj.mutableSetValue(forKey: "folder")
                    let  myObj = new.allObjects as? [Folders]
                    for i in myObj!{
                        if newObj.isExpandable{
                            if newProjectArray.contains(newObj) {

                                foldersArray.append(i)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }`

Comment: To much code to post as comment, I'll post an answer instead.

Comment: Sure, that may help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to fetch the Folders entities since you have defined a one-to-many relationship between Project and Folders this is handled by Core Data

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Project>(entityName: "Project")
let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "pname", ascending: true)
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

do {
    let newProjectArray = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
}catch let error as NSError {
    print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
}
```

And in the other code

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return (newProjectArray != nil) ? newProjectArray!.count : 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection
    section: Int) -> Int {
    if newProjectArray![section].isExpandable, let folders =  newProjectArray![section].folders { 
        return folders.count
    } 
    else{
        return 0
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection
    section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 40
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath:
    IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:
        "FoldersCell") as! FoldersCell
    if  newProjectArray![indexPath.section].isExpandable == true {
        if let folders = newProjectArray![indexPath.section].folders {
            folder = folders[indexPath.row]
            cell.projectNameLabel.text = folder.name
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

The above code has been changed directly in the web browser and is not compiled so it might not be complete accurate but it is hopefully enough to help you solve this

Comment: Hi Joakim, thanks a lot, you saved my life, fantastic it worked